# Is accessing arguments without having explicitly parsed them browser friendly?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, dom-events

Take for example this

```
window.removeEventListener('keyup', this.handleTabKey);
```

...

```
handleTabKey(e){
    console.log('Handle Tab Key', e)
    if(e.which == 9){
        //this will run, as 'e' will be available
    }
}
```

This will work in the latest versions of Chrome and Firefox. What's browser support like for other major browsers? What is the lowest version of IE supported? If possible, what is this inexplicit functionality called and where can I read more about it?

Comment: If the browser supports `removeEventListener` then it will also pass the event object to the handler. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) for which version of IE supports `addEventListener`.

Comment: Thanks Felix - add your answer and I'll mark it correct.

Comment: What do you mean by "*without having explicitly parsed them*"?

Answer (score 0):

`addEventListener` and `removeEventLister` events are `available` for IE>=9.

For IE<9 you need to use `detachEvent`.

Comment: Do you mean IE>=9 or IE9+? ;)

Comment: Yes, I correct to `IE>=9`. Internet Explorer 9, also,  supports `addEventListener` method.